# Changing MultiAutoCompleteTextView Adapter Mid-phrase

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, autocompletetextview

When the user is typing something into my MultiAutoCompleteTextView, I re-check the list of available phrases after each space. Some of my suggested values contain spaces, and I expect that the user will be able to type a space and have the suggested values continue to list only strings that begin with the entered word, so long as my `ITokenizer`'s `FindTokenStart` function returns the position representing the beginning of the word before the space. This is actually working in cases where I don't change the `Adapter` to a different value when typing space. But there's a problem if it changes when typing space.

For example, I have the phrase "Lunch Token" in my suggested value list, and as I begin to type it, everything looks fine:

[image]

It continues to look good up through the end of the word "Lunch". Then I add a space, and I have some logic that detects that because the full word lunch has been entered, a couple of the options are no longer valid. So it switches the `Adapter` property of the MultiAutoCompleteTextView to a different adapter that has fewer words in it. But doing this while the list is popped up appears to cause the list to get populated with all the possible values:

[image]

I have added code in my FindTokenStart function to verify that is is returning the right values, and it is. So it must have something to do with changing the adapter while the list is popped up. How do I work around this and force the list to continue to only display matching terms? I tried only updating the Adapter when the new list was *not* a subset of the prior list, but this causes other problems (I can't remember them at the moment).

Highest level code that changes the Adapter property:

```
private void Command_AfterTextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.AfterTextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      if (!(command.Text.EndsWith(" ") || command.Text.Length == 0))
         return;

      var words = new SuggestionCache.WordList();
      if (command.Text.Length > 0)
         words.AddFromParserStates(parser.ParsePartial(command.Text, currentStory));
      else
         words.AddFromSyntaxes(Syntax.currentSyntaxes);
      command.Adapter = suggestions.GetArrayAdapter(words);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      ShowMessage(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

FindTokenStart implementation:

```
public int FindTokenStart(ICharSequence text, int cursor)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("FindTokenStart: ");
   if ((currentWordList == null) || (currentWordList.tokenBounds.Count == 0))
   {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("A 0");
      return 0;
   }
   int idx = currentWordList.tokenBounds.BinarySearch(new Syntax.SyntaxMatch() { startPos = cursor }, SyntaxMatchComparer.EndComparer);
   if (idx >= 0)
   {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("B {0}", currentWordList.tokenBounds[idx].startPos);
      return currentWordList.tokenBounds[idx].startPos;
   }
   if (~idx < currentWordList.tokenBounds.Count)
   {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("C {0}", currentWordList.tokenBounds[~idx].startPos);
      return currentWordList.tokenBounds[~idx].startPos;
   }
   var lastBound = currentWordList.tokenBounds.LastOrDefault((b) => b.matched == 2);
   if (lastBound.NextPos <= cursor)
   {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("D {0}", lastBound.NextPos);
      return lastBound.NextPos;
   }
   else
   {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("E {0}", lastBound.startPos);
      return lastBound.startPos;
   }
}
```

Debug output while pressing the space key:

```
[0:] FindTokenStart: 
[0:] D 5
[0:] FindTokenStart: 
[0:] D 5
[0:] FindTokenStart: 
[0:] D 5
[0:] FindTokenStart: 
[0:] B 5
01-11 19:08:10.743 E/Surface ( 3326): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9a5e7d60
01-11 19:08:10.759 E/EGL_emulation( 3326): tid 3369: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
01-11 19:08:10.759 W/OpenGLRenderer( 3326): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x98422b20, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin top develop this Android application, and testing it on the Android emulator if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be necessary to change the adapter for a MultiAutoCompleteTextView mid-phrase. The expectation is that all the options are given to the adapter, and the adapter filters that list as more characters are provided, determining which options are still relevant within the current token/phrase. The reason I was changing adapters so often was out of laziness about determining the appropriate times to determine what new adapter should be applied. It shouldn't be based only on a space separator if space is not always the terminator of a token.

My solution was to make the code smarter in trying to ensure that the adapter is only updated at the separation between two tokens. This was relatively easy to accomplish because my existing parser knew where the last token ended and where the next should begin. When these were the same, it means that the token was still incomplete. Once a complete token value was entered and terminated by whitespace, the end of the last token would be less than the beginning of the next token. So by adding this condition before updating the adapter, my problem is resolved:

```
if (words.tokenBounds.Count == 0 || words.tokenBounds.Last().NextPos > words.tokenBounds.Last().EndPos)
    command.Adapter = suggestions.GetArrayAdapter(words);
```